# Prove or disprove: If A, B, and C are nonempty sets, and A × B = A × C, then B = C

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't really understand much about discrete mathematics and proofs because our prof. sucks and I've watched videos and read the textbook. Still don't know where to even start with this question. Please explain what I have to do step by step in detail.

Question: Prove or disprove. If A, B, and C are non-empty sets, and $A \times B = A \times C$ , then $B = C$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Pick some $a \in A$. Then, use that for each $b \in B$ you have $(a,b) \in A \times B=A \times C$ and that for each $c \in C $ you have  $(a,c) \in A \times C=A \times B$.

Comment: where do I go from there? I kind of understand that part. But don't you have to prove it both from the left side **and** the right side? And after proving $ A \times B = A \times C$, how do we prove that B is equal to C?

Comment: @Al.  $A \times B = A \times C$ is GIVEN to you by the problem, you don't need to prove it... First, before starting to prove the problem, write for yoruself clearly what is given and what you want to prove.... Second, you should know the answer to this: how do we usually prove equality of sets? The technique is standard and the instructor very likely mention it few times.

Comment: I understand that $ A \times B$ and $A \times C$ both contain the element $a$ but I don't understand what else your Answer proves. Does it mean that $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ are equal?